# kube-dns does not work

Tags: kubernetes, skydns, kube-dns

I've created cluster(Centos 7) and deploy rc with kube-dns. Cluster works fine but kube-dns prints error in log.

```
    I0817 12:40:01.589924       1 dns.go:299] could not find service for endpoint "kubernetes" in namespace "default"
I0817 12:40:01.591584       1 dns.go:299] could not find service for endpoint "kube-scheduler" in namespace "kube-system"
I0817 12:40:01.591608       1 dns.go:299] could not find service for endpoint "kube-controller-manager" in namespace "kube-system"
I0817 12:40:01.591620       1 dns.go:299] could not find service for endpoint "kube-dns" in namespace "kube-system"
```

apiserver:
    ###
    # kubernetes system config
    #
    # The following values are used to configure the kube-apiserver
    #

```
# The address on the local server to listen to.
KUBE_API_ADDRESS="--address=0.0.0.0"

# The port on the local server to listen on.
KUBE_API_PORT="--port=8080"

# Port minions listen on
KUBELET_PORT="--kubelet-port=10250"

# Comma separated list of nodes in the etcd cluster
KUBE_ETCD_SERVERS="--etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:2379"

# Address range to use for services
KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES="--service-cluster-ip-range=10.10.150.0/19"

# default admission control policies
KUBE_ADMISSION_CONTROL="NamespaceLifecycle,NamespaceExists,LimitRanger,SecurityContextDeny,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota"
# Add your own!
```

master config file:

```
KUBE_LOGTOSTDERR="--logtostderr=true"

ENABLE_CLUSTER_DNS="${KUBE_ENABLE_CLUSTER_DNS:-true}"
DNS_SERVER_IP="10.10.150.250"
DNS_DOMAIN="cluster.local"
DNS_REPLICAS=1

# journal message level, 0 is debug
KUBE_LOG_LEVEL="--v=0"

# Should this cluster be allowed to run privileged docker containers
KUBE_ALLOW_PRIV="--allow-privileged=false"

# How the controller-manager, scheduler, and proxy find the apiserver
KUBE_MASTER="--master=http://127.0.0.1:8080"
```

Does anybody know what happen?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in my SELinux... When I disabled it and all works.

Comment: Downvoted, not only this suggestion does not work but it is dangerous from security standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/hack/local-up-cluster.sh#L352

KUBE_ENABLE_CLUSTER_DNS should be true for DNS to work.
--cluster-dns=10.10.150.250 
--cluster_domain=cluster.local

Comment: I've got these lines in config.. I applied last one to this ticket. Also I've cleaned my etcd cluster and restarted all masters and modes. And I've received  similar problem but with  kube-controller-manager and kube-scheduler